# Registering an Azure AD B2C application with PowerBI

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, powerbi-embedded

All the references online use Azure AD - is it possible to use Azure AD B2C with PowerBI?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you looking to do?

Comment: We are using AAD B2C for authentication, and want to simplify the access to PowerBI - guess the two will need to be separate steps... thought the accessToken could be shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to use Azure AD B2C tokens to access PowerBI dashboards. I would encourage you to vote for this feature [here](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c).

Comment: Really appreciate the answer. Thank you